# How do we solve the system of equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do we solve the system of equations?
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
47a^3+129ab^2-93ba^2-83b^3-154a^2-178b^2+276ab = 0,\\
2a^2+5b^2=23.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Comment: If you substitute the second into the first and square to get rid of the square roots, you will have a sixth degree equation in a.  As you know two solutions, you can divide it down to fourth degree, which is solvable with difficulty or you can go numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the first equation and substitute $b^2=\frac15 (23-2a^2)$
$$\begin{align*} 0 &= 47a^3+129ab^2-93ba^2-83b^3-154a^2-178b^2+276ab \\
 &= 47a^3+129a\frac15 (23-2a^2)-93ba^2-83b\frac15 (23-2a^2)-154a^2-178\frac15 (23-2a^2)+276ab\\
 &= \frac15\left( -23a^3+2967a-299ba^2-1909b-414a^2-4094+1380ab\right)\end{align*}$$
Hence $\hspace{20pt}23a^3+414a^2-2967a+4094=-(299a^2-1380a+1909)b$, i.e.
$$b=-\frac{23a^3+414a^2-2967a+4094}{299a^2-1380a+1909}$$
Substituting back, we get:
$$5\left(23a^3+414a^2-2967a+4094\right)^2=\left(23-2a^2\right)\left(299a^2-1380a+1909\right)^2$$
$$181447 a^6-1555260 a^5+4210311 a^4-2898920 a^3-1804419 a^2-285660 a-14283=0$$
Using the two known roots, $a=3$ and $a=-\frac17$, we get:
$$(a-3)(7a+1)\left(25921 a^4-148120 a^3+189382 a^2+63480 a+4761\right)$$
You have a 4th degree polynomial, which can be solved using [Ferrari formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation).
Using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=181447%20a%5E6-1555260%20a%5E5%2b4210311%20a%5E4-2898920%20a%5E3-1804419%20a%5E2-285660%20a-14283), we have $529 (a-3)^3 (7 a+1)^3$, so $a=3$ and $a=-\frac17$ are the only roots.

Answer (score 1):

$a=3,b=1$ satisfies the equation $2a^2+5b^2=23$

Putting these values in the first , it satisfies first also. Thus, one point of intersection of these curves is $(3,1)$

I want to add that:

If you find $1$ root , try to check whether it is a repeated root or not.

Here, you can check it as : consider two equations as two curves and since $(3,1)$ is the point of intersection , check whether at $(3,1)$ these two curves have a common tangent; if that's the case, then $(3,1)$ is the repeated root.

Comment: Another solution is $\left(-\dfrac{1}{7}; -\dfrac{15}{7}\right)$. But I want to know the way we can find this solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an "in principle" method.

You can substitute a value for $a^2$ $(= \frac{23-5b^2}2)$ from the second equation into the first, which leaves you with a linear equation for $a$ (coefficients are powers of $b$). Solve for $a$, substitute into the second equation and clear fractions to obtain a polynomial for $b$.

Comment: This is similar in spirit to Ross Millikan's comment, but avoids handling expressions with square roots.

Comment: I think this still gets you to sixth degree, and then to fourth after removing the known roots.  The equation for $a$ will be cubic in $b$ and the squaring is the same.

Comment: @RossMillikan - indeed - your comment was posted as I was finishing mine off and wondering whether it merited being put up as an answer. I have just kept $a$ rather than an expression with a square root (I get a fraction instead). I think the method depends on personal taste (I chose mine because I find it easier to organise on paper) and also whether you spot any nice cancellations as you go through.